# Integrating a self-hosted jitsi instance in React app

Tags: reactjs, vps, jitsi, jitsi-meet

Given the recent change of limiting calls to 5 minutes, I successfully self-hosted a jitsi instance on my own vps.

I have a React app hosted on another server. It integrates jitsi meet, using the [jutsu framework](https://github.com/this-fifo/jutsu).

This framework uses the public jitsi instance so the calls are limited to 5 minutes.

```
<body>
  <script src='https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js'></script>
</body>
```

I couldn't figure out how to make it use my own self-hosted instance instead of the public one.

Any help or suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. All I had to do is add
    `domain="domain_name"`

to the options here

```
   <Jutsu
         
          roomName={room_name}
        
          domain="domain_name"`
```